# Java AWT 1.3 to Codename One

Tags: java, awt, codenameone

I want to know if it is at all possible to take an old java 1.3 application and wrap the java.awt components with the CodenameOne components. Is this possible?

The reason for this is a client... like always wants a rushed solution to use before we do a full rewrite.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since the Codename One API is similar to AWT/Swing, it probably wouldn't be that hard to just change a few imports, and then touch up as necessary where the API differs.  Of course some concepts are very different between desktop and mobile (e.g. multiple windows, menus, etc..) so those might be harder to massage.

E.g.  You would change `java.awt.Label` to `com.codename1.ui.Label`, and `java.awt.Button` to `com.codename1.ui.Button`, etc...

[This article](http://boardspace.net/english/codename1-port/Porting%20Boardspace.html), wrtitten by a member of the Codename One community, describes the process he used to port a fairly complex set of AWT/Swing Apps into Codename One.  You might find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is really helpful